# I am trying to use AJAX with Drupal 6. How do I determine the URL I am trying to contact?

Tags: 6, ajax, javascript

I looked at the documentation [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/305747) and it left me a bit confused. I don't need to access any files, I am just returning the date that is on the server to my Javascript code. (I don't want the date/time from the user's perspective)

The example gives this in the javascript portion of the example. This example seems to already know where get should call to get the response back. I am not sure what the URL would be on my server to just talk to my php code.

```
$.get('/photos/get/photos/' + parseInt(this.id, 10), null, imageDetails);
        return false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure what the URL would be on my server to just talk to my php code.

It's the path implemented from your module. In the example, they use /photos/get/photos because in `mymodule_menu()` they define that as path handled by the module.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function mymodule_menu() {
  $items['photos/get/photos'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'mymodule_get_photos_ajax',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

It's you who defines the path, so you know it.

Comment: So I can put any random file structure in the php code and I just need to use the same thing in my java script code?

Comment: Instead of photos/get/photos, you can use any path, as long as no other module uses it, and you use the same path in both `hook_menu()` and the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you use is the one that delivers you the data you want.  If you want to grab the server time you can create a short PHP script that gets the info and then make that info available to JS using Drupal.settings.

For example:

```
// Create the array that is required by drupal_add_js()
$server_time = array(
  'serverTime' => date("h:i:sa"),
);

// This is what makes the variable available to JS
drupal_add_js(array('time' => $server_time), 'setting');
```

Then, in your.js:

```
var time = Drupal.settings.time.serverTime;
```

Comment: This looks like it will fit my needs. But I would like to learn how to use ajax. I will look into it more on Tuesday when I will be near my desktop.